# Привязать свойство Content у Label к переменной из другого класса

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Короче, есть Label, ну, допустим, он называется `label01`, у меня есть класс лежащий в другой папке, к примеру, Core/Strings.cs.

Я хочу забиндить значение `Content` у Label к значению переменной `string0001` в Strings.cs, к примеру:

```
public const string String0001 = "Текст";
```

К этой переменной должен быть привязан Label.
Т.е я изменю текст `String0001` с "Текст" на "Кек" и в лейбл тоже должно изменится.

Я пробовал такой вариант, ну или думал что что-то похоже

```
Content="{Binding Source, Source=String0007}"
```

Comment: Привязка осуществляется только к свойствам, не полям! Для успешной привязки нужный класс должен быть задан как DataContext (либо то, что инициализирует этот класс). Также, для того, что бы из кода менять данные и они отображались во View - надо реализовать INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать так:

Укажите пространство в разметке XAML, предположим

`xmlns:core="clr-namespace:MyProject.Core"`

Затем указать контекст для окна в CodeBehind:

`DataContext = new Strings()`

И для удобства можно:

`d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance core:Strings}"`

И уже после биндить (разумеется к свойству, как и сказал EvgeniyZ)

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding string0001}">`

Comment: Знаете за что минус? 1. Повторю и тут, к полям привязка не работает! 2. Вы советуете указать `d:DataContext`, где `d:` - это чисто дизайнер студии, на работу приложения не как не скажется.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Писал по памяти (которая не очень)), а про свойство, тут просто невнимательность

Comment: Не очень понял, куда засунуть DataContext = new Strings();? Я засунул в код окна в public TestWindow(), не в класс в котором переменная.

Comment: @MairwunNx Да, туда, только нужно добавить в `using` путь к классу, допустим `using MyProject.Core`

Comment: @dmepty | Не работает, все вроде сделал правильно, в окне в котором нужна привязка вписал `xmlns:core="clr-namespace:SacredUtils.Resources.Core"` так же вписал `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance core:AppStrings}"` добавил чуточку тут `<Label x:Name="ColorLabel" Content="{Binding String0001}"/>` ну и под конец в коде того класса         `public AppStrings()
        {
            DataContext = new AppStrings();
        }` Ошибка, в XAML на `Binding String0001.`

Comment: @MairwunNx Я подозреваю, что вы не учли комментарий EvgeniyZ. Привязывать нужно свойство, а не поле.

Comment: @dmepty | Можно пожалуйста образец? Я просто смотрел много инфы по этому, там кода с этими биндингами к переменной больше чем бы я сделал на обычном шарпе. Можно ли как то коротко сделать? Просто я не думал что к переменной привязаться так сложно.

Comment: @dmepty я вот так еще делал, и привязывался к MyText, в редакторе текст есть, а в программе нет.        `public string MyText
        {
            get { return String0008; }
        }`

Comment: @MairwunNx Короче некуда) Не понимаю, что у вас не работает, только что повторил у себя, всё отображается

Comment: @dmepty | Не понимаю как тка, можете скинуть ссылку на проект? Вроде все 1 в 1 сделал.

Comment: [Вот](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MTNlsU5Tj6P4g_QyaJzUOiys6GFz7Ajh)

Comment: @dmepty | Спасибо, ща посмотрю))

Comment: @dmepty Что-то не выходит, возможно из-за расположения моего класса в другой папке? Есть вк, телеграм, почта? Там продолжил бы переписку.

Comment: @MairwunNx Можем продолжить в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78805/binding)

Comment: @dmepty | Дааааа, с радостью бы, да у меня как я понял репутации не хватает что бы писать там, вижу только сообщения твои. А сам не могу, я думал что я на столько отупел что не могу найди поле для ввода сообщения.

Comment: @MairwunNx Хорошо), вот [VK](https://vk.com/id41946345)

Comment: @MairwunNx Вы не забывайте, что данный ресурс работает по принципу "ценность для сообщества". Если вы будете переписываться в другой соц. сети, то в чем ценность данного вопроса для остальных?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ценность это хорошо, но я буквально не могу приложить фото к этом комментарию что усложняет, но если я найду ответ я обязательно им поделюсь сюда.

Comment: @MairwunNx Все, что связано с вопросом публикуется в самом вопросе. Под ним есть кнопка "редактировать". Ну а так, я вот читаю вашу переписку и не понимаю что у вас не работает, как мне и другим людям в таком случае вам помогать?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь @dmepty |

Есть класс который находится в проекте по пути Resources/Core/AppStrings.cs, в нем есть переменная string0001.

Есть окно ColorWindow, в котором свойство Content в Label должно быть привязано к string0001.

Как выше писал чел надо указать пространство в разметке XAML в окне.

```
xmlns:core="clr-namespace:SacredUtils.Resources.Core"
```

Затем добавить вот эту строку под строкой выше тоже в окне.

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance core:AppStrings}"
```

Затем добавить вот это `DataContext = new AppStrings();` в ColorWindow() { ... } (ColorWindow.cs) код окна где находится сам label.

Потом в классе со строчками (AppStrings.cs) добавить

```
public string String0001 = "Текст";

public string MyText => String0001;
```

И потом просто привязать это к Label так:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyText}"/>
```

Comment: Можно даже сразу так. `public string MyText => "Текст";`