# (UWP C#) Приложение обратилось к интерфейсу, относящемуся к другому потоку

Tags: c#, uwp, tcp, visual-studio-2019

Нашел пример реализации консольного TCP-чата на С# и решил попробовать перенести его клиент на UWP. В примере было два приложения, клиентское и серверное. В качестве сервера я использую серверное консольное приложение из примера и подключаюсь к нему с помощью UWP-клиента, вместо консольного из примера.
Но суть не в этом.

Суть в следующем. Имеется метод ReceiveMessage():

```
public void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[64];
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = SettingsPage.stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (SettingsPage.stream.DataAvailable);

                ChatPage.Message = builder.ToString();                  
                //MessageWriterAsync(ChatPage.Message);
                
            }
            catch
            {
                ChatPage.Message = "Подключение прервано";
                ChatPage.DisconnectRequest();
            }
        }

    }
```

Данный метод я использую для получения сообщения и он работает в потоке, который в свою очередь запускается при подключении к серверу. При получении сообщения я выполняю код MessageWriterAsync(string MessageToWrite), в который сообщаю строку Message из ChatPage:

```
public async void MessageWriterAsync(string MessageToWrite)
    {
        ChatPage Ch = new ChatPage();


        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (MessageToWrite != "")
                {
                    Ch.boxChat.Text = MessageToWrite;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

который будет записывать полученное сообщение (переменная Message) в TextBox по имени boxChat. Но, к моему сожалению, это не работает( Если убрать комментирование в методе ReceiveMessage() перед вызовом MessageWriterAsync я получаю исключение

[![Исключение][1]][1]

Помогите, пожалуйста(((
Объясните чайнику, что он делает не так?

---

**UPD 9.01.2020 19:10**

Прибиндил строковую переменную ChatHistory к boxChat.Text, для чего создал отдельный класс Strings в папке Resources:

```
public class Strings : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _ChatHistory;
        public string ChatHistory 
        {

            get { return _ChatHistory; } 
            
            set
            {
                if (_ChatHistory != value)
                {
                    _ChatHistory = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ChatHistory");
                }
            } 

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

    }
```

Затем в XAMLе страницы с boxChat добавил

```
<Page ...
    ...
    xmlns:local="using:MyNamespace.Resources"
    ...
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:Strings ChatHistory="История чата" />
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="boxChat" Text="{Binding ChatHistory}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

а в коде этой страницы добавил:

```
   public ChatPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new Strings { ChatHistory = "История чата" };
            connected = false;
        }
   ...
   public void AddString(string String)
        {
            Strings strings = this.DataContext as Strings;
            strings.ChatHistory += "\r\n" + String;
        }
   ...
```

Затем я немного изменил ReceiveMessage()

```
   void ReceiveMessage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[64];
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (stream.DataAvailable);

                    string message = builder.ToString();
                    Strings StringsLink = new Strings();
                    StringsLink.ChatHistory += "\r\n" + message;

                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Теперь при вызове AddString (например при нажатии кнопки) мой boxChat обновляется и добавляет условную строку string. Но при получении сообщения с помощью Receivemessage() моя строка Chathistory получает значение message но boxChat почему-то не обновляет это значение. Буду копать дальше.

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы 1. Используете криво технологию, ибо в WPF, UPF, Xamarin, принято использовать привязки, а не напрямую обращаться к UI объектам. То есть, у вас должен быть установлен источник данных (в WPF это `DataContext`, в UWP аналог думаю найдете), в этом источнике должны быть свойства, например `public string Text {get; set;}` (если обновляется через код, то INPC не забудьте), ну и в XAML у вас не `<TextBlock x:Name="tb1"/>`, а `<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Text}">`, где `Text` - созданное свойство (`Binding` также по аналоги ищите, имена могут быть разные).

Comment: 2. Из-за того, что вы обращаетесь к UI напрямую, а ваше TCP идет в другом потоке, у вас и возникает эта проблема, что на скрине. В таких целях используют либо диспетчер, либо более современный и надежный вариант - `IProgress`, который оповестит об изменение нужного значения. Об этом можете почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418461/220553). А, ну и также странно, что вы делаете `ChatPage Ch = new ChatPage();` на каждый вызов события, вы уверены в этом?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с контролами из фонового потока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Ваша функция внутри `Dispatcher.RunAsync` намертво блокирует UI-поток. Не делайте так. Вы должны, например, подписаться на изменения, и только в нужный момент обновлять UI, а не крутить бесконечный поллинг.

Comment: Ещё, я полагаю, у вас сделана классическая ошибка получения данных: вы читаете _часть_ байтов с помощью `stream.Read` и применяете `Unicode.GetString` к этой части. А нужно сперва получить _все_ данные, а потом их декодировать в строку.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Добавил бинд переменной TextMessage к свойству Text моего boxChat по аналогии [как здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841284/424173). Кроме того, использовал INPC, как вы и сказали. Для этого пришлось создать класс AddMessage, в котором и лежит TextMessage. Теперь в том же месте где и выше выпрыгивает исключение System.StackOverflowException. Кстати, ссылку на объект использовал потому что мой boxChat  находится в другом классе (приложение на двух страницах)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov исправил, основываясь на ваше замечание. На результат не повлияло, но все равно спасибо за совет. Принял к сведению.

Comment: @VladD не могли бы подробнее объяснить, если не затруднит?

Comment: `выпрыгивает исключение System.StackOverflowException` - вангую, что у вас `public SomeProperty {get => SomeProperty; set => SomeProperty = value;}`... Если да, то это зацикливание. Если нет, то без кода я вряд-ли смогу вам сказать что не так.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, вы правы, похоже я не очень внимателен. Ну, я думаю, простительно, ведь я новичок (не [этот](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BA_(%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)) XD) в шарпе. Как в таком случае заполнить гетсетеры, или не нужно?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/644314/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сделал, все равно ошибка(

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ```public class AddMessage : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string TextMessage { get; set; }
        //{ get { }; set { OnPropertyChanged("TextMessage");} }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }```

Comment: `все равно ошибка` - вы ведь понимаете, что ошибок в мире уйма и о какой мне думать?) Если та, что в вопросе, то значит вы не до конца поняли мои первые два сообщения. Посмотрите ссылку, где "возможно дубликат", там есть `Решение с отображением прогресса выполнения`, вот попробуйте это сделать, только (s => label1.Text = s)` - будет `(s=> TextMessage = s)`. А да, в коде выше, вы не вызываете INPC, это не обновит интерфейс, если свойство будет изменено через код.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не могли бы отправить ссылку с годным материалом о правильном использовании INotifyPropertyChanged и привязок?

Comment: Ну например, [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553). Весь MVVM по желанию (но рекомендую), а IMPC и другое смотрите сами как и что используется. Правда там под WPF, но отличия от UWP по сути в названиях. Сами реализации INPC и ICommand бывают разные, в этом ответе например ICommand урезанный, ибо мне не нужно было "может выполняться или нет", но по его аналогии думаю без труда найдете в интернете полный вариант.